# A question about convex functions

Tags: calculus

> c. If $F$ is convex and $t_0\in(a,b)$, there exists $\beta\in\mathbb R$ such that $F(t)-F(t_0)\ge\beta(t-t_0)$ for all $t\in(a,b)$.

It seems intuitively clear, and I thought proving it would not be hard..but now I can't find a way to approach. Could anyone tell me how to prove this?

Comment: What is your definition of a convex function?

Answer (score 2):

Use the convexity of $F$ to show that the function

$$\hat F(t)=\frac{F(t)-F(t_0)}{t-t_0}$$

defined for $t\in(a,b)\setminus\{t_0\}$ is monotonic non-decreasing. (This should be possible to show whatever your definition of "convex function" is, but the proof will depend on the definition.) This means the right-hand and left-hand limits of $\hat F(t)$ at $t=t_0$ are defined. Clearly the right-hand limit is not less than the left-hand limit.

Let $\beta$ be any value between those two one-sided limits (perhaps equal to one or both of them). Show that the inequality holds for that $\beta$.